# VBA - Saving all worksheets as separate files with a file name based on a cell

Tags: excel, save, filenames, vba

I've found code to save all the worksheets, and I've found code to save the file with a filename based on a cell, but I can't seem to get both to work at the same time.  Below is my entire macro - but the problem seems to stem from the last section: Sub(SheetSplit).  I've tried all sorts of methods I've found online, but I need this to happen with a relative path - as in the same folder in which the workbooks are.  The code is in a workbook called "Remit Macros.xls" and the multi-tabbed workbook I'm messing with is "RemitReport.xls" - what am I missing here?  I always get an error of "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed.  What gives?  I included the rest of the code in case it helps.

```
Sub RemitTotal()
    '
    ' Highlights remit amounts great enough for additional approvals
    '
    Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\RemitReport.xls")
    Windows("RemitReport.xls").Activate

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select

        BeginRow = 6
        EndRow = Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
        ChkCol = 18

        For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow - 9
            If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value > 500000 Then
                Range("R6:R1000").Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ColorIndex = 6
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                End With
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next i

    Call DateMacro

End Sub

Sub DateMacro()
    '
    ' Highlights dates not in the current month, i.e. early or late payments
    '
    Windows("RemitReport.xls").Activate

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select

        BeginRow = 6
        EndRow = Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
        ChkCol = 6

        For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow - 9
            If IsDate(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol)) And Month(Date) <> Month(Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol - 1).Value) Then
                'date values no longer need to be updated monthly
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol - 1).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                .ColorIndex = 10
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                End With
            End If
        Next RowCnt

        BeginRow = 6
        EndRow = Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
        ChkCol = 6

        For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow - 9
            If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol - 1) + 30 Then
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Select
                With Selection.Interior
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .Pattern = xlSolid
                End With
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    Next i

    Call RemitNames

End Sub

Sub RemitNames()
    '
    'Adds lender remit name in the active worksheets in order to facilitate
    'saving each sheet under a different filename indicative of lender
    '
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Sheets(i).Select

        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Range("D1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("E1").Select

        ActiveCell.Formula = "=RIGHT(D1,LEN(D1)-FIND("": "",D1))"
        Range("F1").Formula = "=TRIM(E1)"
        Range("D3:S3").Select
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        Selection.Merge
        Range("J1").Formula = "=INDEX('[Remit Macros.xls]Remit Codes'!$B1:$B999,MATCH(F1,'[Remit Macros.xls]Remit Codes'!$A1:$A999,0))"
        Range("J1").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Range("D1:F1").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Range("J1").Select

    Next i

    Call SheetSplit

End Sub

Sub SheetSplit()
    '
    'Creates an individual workbook for each worksheet in the active workbook.
    '
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim sht As Object
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim sname As String
    Dim relativePath As String

    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sht In wbSource.Sheets

        sht.Copy
        Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook

        sname = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & ".xls"
        relativePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sname
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=relativePath, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Range("A1").Clear

    Next

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Edit: After several of the suggestions I've been given, here is the last section of the code.  It still doesn't work, but I think it's getting closer.  I've also cleaned it up a little bit.

```
Sub SheetSplit()
'Creates an individual workbook for each worksheet in the active workbook.
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim sht As Object
Dim strSavePath As String
Dim sname As String
Dim origpath As String
Dim relativePath As String
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
    origpath = wbSource.Path
    'relativePath = origpath & "\" & sname
    'sname = sht.Range("A1") & ".xls"
        For Each sht In wbSource.Sheets
            sht.Copy
            Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook
            sname = sht.Range("A1") & ".xls"
            relativePath = origpath & "\" & sname
            'relativePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sname
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=relativePath, FileFormat:=56
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
'Range("A1").Clear
Next
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: `SaveAs` can fail if you are trying to save over a file that is read-only. Have you checked to make sure you aren't trying to save over existing files? It may help to temporarily comment out the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` line so you can see any file-related error prompts until you fix the error.

Comment: I will try commenting that line out to get some more detail - but there are no other files in the directory I'm using.

Comment: Sure there are no other files, that is, until you start saving the new files there via the macro. My guess would be that some of the values in cell A1 of the sheets are the same so it's trying to save over a file that the macro just saved and still has open since you do not close the new workbooks after saving them. It seems you need to figure out what to do if the file already exists because a previous sheet had the same name in cell A1.

Comment: The macro was intended to be used in a clean folder each time, in practice it will be in a different folder each day beginning with no files and the folder name being the current day's date.  The macro hasn't gotten far enough (due to the error) to save the first file, but when I check the folder just in case, there are still no other files there - just the macro file and the source file that is being used to generate the different reports to be saved. Edit to clarify: even in testing I run it in a clean folder every time.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure `relativePath` is a valid file path and name, no invalid characters?

Comment: relativePath is defined as Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/" & sname, sname is defined as ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range ("J1") & ".xls" - the information in cell J1 doesn't include any non-alphanumeric characters except spaces.

Comment: According to the code in your question:`sname = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") & ".xls"`
        `relativePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sname` - You might try adding a Watch for `relativePath` and manually checking that the string is a valid file path. The only other thing I can think of is that the file extension has to be valid for the `FileFormat:=` also. It won't let you save a .XLSM format with a .XLS extension- just as an example.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a watch?  Also, the site I was reading about this code from said that the format =x1Excel18 was the xls format.  I'm going to read up on that, it never occurred to me that that could be incorrect.

Comment: Also, I tried looking up the fileformat codes and saw that "56" was the code for xls...tried that to get the same error.  Given that the macro itself is not in the file that I'm trying to save - does the file I'm trying to save need to be xlsm format?  The recipients of these files require xls format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, see comments in the code.

```
Sub SheetSplit()
    '
    'Creates an individual workbook for each worksheet in the active workbook.
    '
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim sht As Object
    Dim strSavePath As String
    Dim sname As String
    Dim relativePath As String

    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each sht In wbSource.Sheets

        sht.Copy
        Set wbDest = ActiveWorkbook

        sname = sht.Range("A1") & ".xls"
        relativePath = wbSource.Path & "\" & sname 'use path of wbSource

        wbDest.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Clear 'clear filename from new workbook cell A1

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=relativePath, FileFormat:=xlExcel8
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True


        wbDest.Close False 'close the newly saved workbook without saving (we already saved)

    Next

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my God it works!  Thank you so much!  The only thing I changed is I  commented out the line that closes them - they have to then be looked at individually before closing, but this is still a great help!

Comment: Glad to help. You can use a "Watch" on variables that you want to check the value of when there is a break, it's a debugging feature of the VBA IDE. MSDN article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440547(v=office.12).aspx If you had set up a watch for the relativePath variable you'd have seen the value was something like "\<filename>.xls" which is an invalid file path.

Answer (score 0):

When the new workbook is created it has not yet been saved so relative path is just \sname so it can't save.

Move the relative pathline above the creation of the new book so:

```
Dim origpath as string, relativePath As String

Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
origpath = wbSource.path
```

Then

```
relativePath = origpath & "\" & sname
```

You also need to change the sheetname line to:

```
sname = sht.Range("A1") & ".xls"
```

And you probably want to close each new book after it has been created or depending on the number of sheets in your original workbook you will have a lot of workbooks open:

```
wbDest.close
```

One final thing is you should be explicit about which `Range("A1")` you are clearing or it could also cause an error if removed from source wb as the next sheetname would be blank

Comment: Deleted my previous comments with a lot of code that was hard to read...so I typed your first line in above Set wbSourse and it had a compile error because in the previous line I had Dim relativePath as string, so I commented the previous line out.  Added your second block right after "origpath = ..." then changed the range reference in the third block.  Commented out the line clearing range A1, and I need to leave them open because they have to each be quickly reviewed.  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes that would give a compile error I meant adjust the original declaration then adjust the relative path assignment which would work exactly as the accepted answer.